# Data Scientist Prerequisites: What are the essential prerequisite statistics topics?

Tags: statistics, beginner

I have may years of experience with database application development mainly focused on SQL Server and Oracle.

I like to move into Data Science field and I my understanding is that I need a solid knowledge of Statistics and background - I wonder if that is correct?

I wonder what are the important statistic topics that I must know as data science prerequisites?

I am reading the following book:

Statistics in a Nutshell 2nd Edition (http://amzn.com/1449316824 )

Which of the following topics are important for data science or is there any other important topic that I must learn before I start Data Science?

- Chapter 3 Inferential Statistics
- Chapter 4 Descriptive Statistics and Graphic Displays
- Chapter 6 The t-Test
- Chapter 7 The Pearson Correlation Coefficient
- Chapter 8 Introduction to Regression and ANOVA
- Analysis of Variance (ANOVA)
- Chapter 10 Multiple Linear Regression
- Chapter 11 Logistic, Multinomial, and Polynomial Regression
- Chapter 12 Factor Analysis, Cluster Analysis, and Discriminant Function Analysis

Thank you

Comment: These types of questions are generally viewed as off-topic for StackExchange

Answer (score 1):

Everything on that list is is important material you should know. The sequence the topics are introduced looks to be chosen so that the material builds on itself as you move through (this effect is never totally perfect but seems generally right in this case), so I'd pretty much read the chapters as they appear.
The material listed is the most basic of basic statistics, so it is hard to make a case to omit something.

However, while knowledge of these topics is important, it is very common (probably 'more common') for data scientists to involved in machine learning, which is a different approach to analysing data which gives better results for prediction. An overlapping term (not completely equivalent) term that is used is 'data mining' - searching on Amazon for these terms will give good results that can be used to pick a book that matches your background.

Note that statistics and machine learning are both heavily dependent on maths, especially calculus, linear algebra and probability. The book you mention has been written for people with little background in these, but to go deeper you'll need to brush up or get new knowledge in these areas.